# What to do if a police officer as oppressed you? Can you take revenge on him?

Tags: police, romania

**Context**

I have heard a disturbing story from my grandmother saying that my aunt was driving her car in a place where there is no traffic and suddenly a police officer has stopped her and suspended my aunt for driving without license or something like this, and they took her permission to drive, and she is not even allowed to drive her car back home, and her home was far away. This really bothered me a lot, and I consider it as an **oppression**.

What can I do so that I can have my revenge on that Romanian police officer for my aunt? Is there anything I can do so that I can do this?

Comment: Revenge is not the appropriate thing to seek. You could seek redress, appeal, and so on. Also in most places you need a proper license to drive, even "in a place where there is no traffic." If her home is far away and there is no public transportation nearby, you might ask if the law requires the officer to give her a ride in this situation rather than leave her stranded, but it is not an "oppression" the way you describe it.

Comment: @Brandin but the police officers told her, “this is not our problem, you suppose to think twice before have done anything”. And they left her just like this in no where. And they haven’t even give her a ride back home… how iditots

Comment: This is after she asked them how she can get home.

Comment: If you focus on the facts someone here could say if officer's actions were lawful. From your description your aunt was driving without a valid license, then an officer stopped her, revoked her license and prevented her from driving home without a license. He then refused to give her a ride home and possibly made a snarky response to her, and that made your aunt angry at the officer.

Comment: @Brandin Yes, or actually she didn’t had a driven license, I’m not so sure what she told me, but surely it is a disturbing story to me.

Comment: If she didn't have a license then she was almost certainly breaking the law.

Comment: @Brandin Yeah but, she was not even in traffic, she was in a nowhere place. This shouldn’t be a big deal, according to my thinking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85970/discussion-between-brandin-and-alex-a).

Comment: @Brandin Blast it, now I’m having problems with logging.

Comment: You need a license to drive, even if there is no traffic. It doesn't matter whether you think tt is ''no big deal" in this situation. Your aunt was probably just angry at the situation and the officer behaved discourteously in response. There is no legal issue here.

Comment: @Brandin Yeah but, generally speaking, and officer should calm down a person who’s angry, right? He could have give her just a ride and track or tow her car back home.

Comment: Technically the officer could probably have had her arrested and thrown in jail, the fact that he just didn't allow her back on the road is proof that the officer was being rather nice about it. Your aunt was breaking the law, the officer did not allow her to continue doing it further. He has no obligation to provide her a ride home and a tow for her car (which would probably be expensive and not covered by his employer).

Comment: @Brandin "Your aunt was probably just angry at the situation and the officer behaved discourteously in response. There is no legal issue here": this isn't necessarily true.  If the officer was abusive, there could well be a legal issue.  It is not clear from the question that the officer was abusive, of course, but the fact that she was driving without a license doesn't mean that anything the officer did was necessarily legal.

Comment: Alex A, there could be laws or policies in place dictating what a police officer must do about a person's car in a situation like this.  I suppose the officer probably followed the law and any policies, but if you look into it in more detail you might find that he did not.  Then you could file a complaint, although I don't suppose that would bring any benefit to your aunt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do so that I can have my revenge on that Romanian police
>   officer for my aunt?

There is definitely no country in the world were it is legal to take revenge on a police officer for the police officer's official actions.

If the policeman acted unlawfully, there may be a right to sue the police officer (U.S. law allows this in some circumstances), but even then, the suit would have to be brought by your aunt in her own name and would have to involve intentional wrongdoing by the police officer.

It is very unlikely that the police officer did anything improper in this case based upon what you have said.

> Is there anything I can do so that I can do this?

No. There is absolutely nothing at all that you can do about this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Romanian laws, but in most places you need a valid driving license to drive a car on a public road, no matter whether there is traffic or not. You can drive on your own land as long as it is not accessible to the public. So it is obvious that she isn't allowed to drive, including driving home.

If the police officer left her there, miles away from anywhere, without a working phone, that might put her into danger if she wasn't capable of walking that distance, so that is something she might complain about.